# Run rvest over vector of webpages with different css selectors

Tags: r, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape contact details from different websites therefore they have different css selectors.

data:

```
website status                   email            phone
1 http://www.saudiacatering.com/en/home     NA info@noorinvestment.com +966 12-686-0011
2  http://www.laithllc.com/contact.html     NA       info@laithllc.com  +971 2-553-7571
               Fax                          cssr
1 +966 12-686-1864                    .w-icon li
2  +971 2-353-7579 p+ p , section:nth-child(1) p
```

I have read every single post on multiple web scraping and they all have the similar URL and similar css selector/xpath.

I did try:

```
library(rvest)
        i<- str_replace_all(file$website, "http://www.[.]+", "")
    urls<- "http://www."
    cssr<- as.vector(file$cssr)
    for (i in urls){
      a01 <- paste0("http://www.",i, sep="")
      text <- read_html(a01) %>%
        html_nodes(cssr) %>% 
        html_text()
```

assuming that the base url is http://www. and the additions are the rest of the website links. however not successful.

any similar applications, am i using the correct package?

new code:

```
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
    i<- str_replace_all(url, "http://www.", "")
urls<- "http://www."
cssr<- as.vector(file$cssr)
for (x in i){
  a01 <- paste0("http://www.",x, sep="")
  read_html(a01)%>%
for(m in cssr){html_nodes(m) %>%html_text()}}

    Error in for (. in m) file$cssr : 
  4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3
```

Comment: You've got `urls<- "http://www."` and then `for(i in urls)`, so `i` is only going to be the same as `urls`, and then you paste `http://www.` onto `i`, so `a01` is going to be `http://www.http://www.`. Its just basically broken. Have another go, and think more carefully about the values of variables. Your URL looks like it should come from the `website` column of your data frame, but you've not used that.

Comment: Also, if you say something is "not successful", you should explain what kind of non-success happened - error message, blank output, computer catches fire? There's usually one way for things to work, and hundreds of ways for them to fail, and knowing which helps us help you.

Comment: @spacedman, you are right. i am new to R and this is the first time i use loops. i did some more reading and added the above code which still gave me error. the below answer does it for me but for the sake of learning i want to know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Spacedman's comments into account, maybe this is what you want:

```
file <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text =
'website  status  email  phone   Fax  cssr
http://www.saudiacatering.com/en/home NA info@noorinvestment.com "+966 12-686-0011" "+966 12-686-1864" ".w-icon li"
http://www.laithllc.com/contact.html NA  info@laithllc.com  "+971 2-553-7571" "+971 2-353-7579" "p+ p , section:nth-child(1) p"')

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
mutate(file, text = map2(website, cssr, ~ read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes(.y) %>% html_text()))
#                                 website status                   email            phone              Fax                          cssr                                                               text
# 1 http://www.saudiacatering.com/en/home     NA info@noorinvestment.com +966 12-686-0011 +966 12-686-1864                    .w-icon li +966 (12) 686-0011, +966 (12) 686-1864, careers@saudiacatering.com
# 2  http://www.laithllc.com/contact.html     NA       info@laithllc.com  +971 2-553-7571  +971 2-353-7579 p+ p , section:nth-child(1) p
```